# ReferenceError: sheet_name is not defined

Tags: google-apps-script, referenceerror

This is some old code we use and I didn't create it (really novice) and now when I try to add more info in the sheets like adding other sheet names it stopped working.
I hope some one can help me, everytime I get:

ReferenceError: sheet_name is not defined
(anonymous) @ IssuesTracker.gs:28

I have 3 spreadsheets, 1 insheet and 2 outsheets. The insheet is connected to forms, in this sheet I have the script. When people fill in the form I want the script to automatically replace the information based on a basic True or False. True going to 1 outsheet and False going to the other outsheet. After this the line should be deleted in the insheet.

```
  function test_onFormSubmit() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreSheet().getDataRange();
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  var headers = data[0];
  var sheet_name = inSheet.getName();
  for (var row=3; row < data.length; row++) {
    var e = {};
    e.values = data[row].filter(Boolean); 
    e.range = dataRange.offset(row,0,1,data[0].length);
    e.namedValues = {};
    for (var col=0; col<headers.length; col++) {
      e.namedValues[headers[col]] = [data[row][col]];
    }
    // Pass the simulated event to onFormSubmit
    onFormSubmit(e);
  }
}

function Tracker(e) {

  var date = new Date();  
  var inSheet = e.range.getSheet();
  var sheet_name = inSheet.getName(); 
  var testColumn = 70;
  var firstRow = 3; 

}
  
    var outSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1XBhmtWmVSI3awTYyibFpRJ92o9hAA1AyMsnA1XIFkj2").getSheetName(sheet_name);
    var outSheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("16MTuClf4KqRcti0arhlYd_NdIVh_DxCpEdTJTiGchf4").getSheetName(sheet_name);
    
    numCols = inSheet.getLastColumn(); 
    numRows = inSheet.getLastRow();
    
    Logger.log("Rows : %s cols : %s",numRows,numCols); 
    
      for ( i=numRows; i>=firstRow; i--){
      if (inSheet.getRange(i,testColumn,1,1).getValue()=="Yes") {
          Logger.log("!!!! Found !!! Moving line : %s",i);
          outSheet.appendRow(inSheet.getRange(i,1,1,numCols).getValues()[0]);
          //inSheet.getRange(i,1,1,numCols).clear({contentsOnly: true});
          inSheet.deleteRow(i);
        }
      else
      if (inSheet.getRange(i,testColumn,1,1).getValue()=="No") {
          Logger.log("!!!! Found !!! Moving line : %s",i);
          outSheet2.appendRow(inSheet.getRange(i,1,1,numCols).getValues()[0]);
          inSheet.getRange(i,1,1,numCols).clear({contentsOnly: true});
          inSheet.deleteRow(i);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please add more details. What function are you running? What is the textual error message? If you haven't done yet, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets.

Comment: Thanks Rubén, following is the error message:

ReferenceError: sheet_name is not defined
(anonymous) @ IssuesTracker.gs:28

Comment: I have 3 spreadsheets, 1 insheet and 2 outsheets. The insheet is connected to forms, in this sheet I have the script. When people fill in the form I want the script to automatically replace the information based on a basic True or False. True going to 1 outsheet and False going to the other outsheet. After this the line should be deleted in the insheet.